# Problems Executing iPhone "GenericKeychain" Example

Tags: ios, iphone

I can't get apple's "GenericKeychain" example to run. I have replaced all 5 occurrences, as mentioned in the readme file, of "YOUR_APP_ID_HERE.com.yourcompany" with my own string: se.[company name].[project name].demo. The compilation goes fine but when trying to run it on the phone, an error saying "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" appears. And yes, I have an ad hoc provisioning profile installed. I've tried to add "Entitlements.plist" with "get-task-allow" checked but with the same result. Has anyone been able to run the example? If that is the case, provide me with instructions on how you got it to run, please.

URL: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GenericKeychain/index.html

Comment: FWIW, if all you are doing is password storage, you should stop sliding down the rabbit hole now and check out this wrapper around the keychain: http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

Answer (score 4):

Check your KeychainAccessGroups.plist and KeychainAccessGroups2.plist.

Change keychain-access-groups item0 and itme1 by doing the following:

1. Go to Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles (on the upper left)
2. Look for the Provisioning Profile you are using to sign your app and click it
3. Look for "App Identifier" that's your App ID

If your provisioning file App ID is ABC123CDF456.*,

item0 is ABC123CDF456.com.yourcompany.GenericKeychain2,

item1 is ABC123CDF456.com.yourcompany.GenericKeychainSuite

Comment: @AOO: you really should start accepting some asnwers. You can start with this one, since it's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `get-task-allow` property should be false/unchecked for AdHoc builds. Have you also correctly set your own reverse domain or app id in the `Info.plist` file?

Comment: I've tested with both checked and unchecked "get-task-allow". The bundle identifier (app id) is set to se.[company name].[project name].demo